# How to get value after a particular string in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json data in this format.

```
({test:[test, "&lt;br/&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Name&lt;/b&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;  James;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Company&lt;/b&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Company1&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Phone.....}).
```

I need to get the value after 'Company' using javascript, is there any possibilities....

Please help me on this....

Comment: your json is absolutely invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your data was in some sort of parsable format, you could do this:

```
var textAfterCompany = data.split('Company')[1];
```

split returns an array of strings, [0] is everything to the left and [1] is everything to the right (assuming there is only one occurrence of 'company')

Comment: I used var data = testdata.toSource(); to get that above mentioned value(Which is mentioned in the Main Question). It works fine in firefox, but i get some error in IE{Object doesn't support this property or method}. So i replaced it with "var answer = JSON.stringify(testdata);" and not it shows "too much recursion" in firefox console. I'm not sure what is the problem. Can you help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = test[1].substring(test[1].indexOf("Company"), test[1].length);
```

Comment: javascript's substring method will automatically use the string's length as the ending if no length is given, you do not need to pass test[1].length